# Problems with SQL query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables related, and I need to make a Query inside another Query joining them, this is what I got so far:

```
SELECT a.idarticulo,
       a.idcategoria,
       c.nombre as categoria,
       a.idarticulo,
       a.idsucursal,
       s.nombre as sucursal,
       (SELECT talla.idtalla,
               talla.nombre,
               articulo_talla.idtalla,
               articulo_talla.cantidad,
               articulo_talla.idarticulo,
               articulo.idarticulo,
               articulo.nombre
        FROM talla
               JOIN articulo_talla ON talla.idtalla = articulo_talla.idtalla
               JOIN articulo ON articulo_talla.idarticulo = articulo.idarticulo
        WHERE articulo.idarticulo = a.idarticulo) as tallaCantidad,
       a.codigo,
       a.nombre,
       a.stock,
       a.descripcion,
       a.imagen,
       a.condicion
FROM articulo a
       JOIN categoria c ON a.idcategoria = c.idcategoria
       JOIN sucursal s ON a.idsucursal = s.idsucursal
ORDER BY idarticulo DESC
```

But it throws me the following error: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please format your code. It's really hard to make the query out as it is presented here.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  You have a scalar subquery, but it is returning too many values.  It can only return one value.

Answer (score 1):

Your subselect contains multiple columns.  If you need only tallaCantidad :

```
SELECT a.idarticulo,a.idcategoria,c.nombre as categoria, a.idarticulo,a.idsucursal,s.nombre as sucursal,
(SELECT talla.idtalla, talla.nombre, articulo_talla.idtalla, articulo_talla.cantidad, articulo_talla.idarticulo, articulo.idarticulo, articulo.nombre
FROM talla
    INNER JOIN articulo_talla ON talla.idtalla=articulo_talla.idtalla
    INNER JOIN articulo ON articulo_talla.idarticulo=articulo.idarticulo
    WHERE articulo.idarticulo=a.idarticulo) as tallaCantidad, a.codigo,a.nombre,a.stock,a.descripcion,a.imagen,a.condicion
FROM articulo a
INNER JOIN categoria c ON a.idcategoria=c.idcategoria
INNER JOIN sucursal s ON a.idsucursal=s.idsucursal
ORDER BY idarticulo DESC
```